# Visual Studio Keeps deleting the VB line connectors ( _ )

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have some visual basic code where i have a for loop and for company syntax reason, we need to include a _ at the en of the from in line. However, whenever I unfocus from the code, the " _ " gets deleted

I tried messing around in the option under Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > advance and unchecking everything but that did not help.
 this is the code i want to produce:

```
 Dim burger = (From p In db.PreviousDeclarations _
Where p.burgerID = CompanyID.Value And Object.Equals(p.Year, Year)
```

This is the code visual studio keep "Correcting" for me:

```
 Dim burger = (From p In db.PreviousDeclarations
Where p.burgerID = CompanyID.Value And Object.Equals(p.Year, Year)
```

Comment: It's not needed anymore. Does your code compile properly without it?

Comment: As of VB 10.0 the need for the underscore to break lines was removed

Comment: my code does compile without it, it's just company policy to keep it

Comment: @Martin: The need for the underscore has only been removed in certain cases (e.g. when the line ends with a comma) as explained here: [Implicit line continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#implicit-line-continuation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck **Pretty listing (reformatting) of code**, located in Options->Text Editor->Basic-> Advanced->Editor Help

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Visual Studio will delete the line continuation characters when they're not necessary, typically when the first line alone would not compile on its own but the line below makes it syntactically valid.  I know from experience that it's annoying when switching to a new VS that does this, as a small change can easily look like a huge refactoring when doing a diff.

I don't believe there's any way to disable the functionality. If you need them for a company style guideline I suggest you update the guidelines